# loop through html inputs that have an ID

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling here with some javascript code I need. I have an html document with more than 300 inputs (type text). All inputs have an id, some inputs also have a name (similar to the id). I want to loop through all input tags that have an ID but do not have a name and for each one add a name attribute identical to the ID.

I think it's simple and I know how to find or loop through elements with specific ID but there is something I'm missing and cant figure it out.

Comment: Please provide us with your attempt to solve this problem

Comment: Why to set `id`s if you can't use them? `document.querySelectorAll('input[id]')` returns you all input elements with `id` attribute set.

Comment: when I created the html file I onyl added id to my tags. Now I need some backend processing in php and also my tags need a name and wanted to add it in a faster way

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll with the attribute selector `[attr]`, loop through and check if it's got a name, if not copy the ID to the name.

eg.

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('input[id]')) {
  if (!el.getAttribute('name')) {
    el.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('id'));
  }
}

console.log(document.querySelector('form').innerHTML);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="bob"/>
  <input id="john"/>
  <input name="gotname"/>
</form>
```

Comment: this is want I wanted. thank you